# Visualize ANCOVA incl formulas (e.g. library HH)

Tags: r, plot, lattice

Package HH seems provide a easy way to visualize ANCOVAs

```
library(HH)
data(hotdog)
ancova(Sodium ~ Calories * Type, data=hotdog)
```

[image]

Is there a comfortable way to combinate this with something like `panel.ablineq` from `latticeExtra`?  (http://latticeextra.r-forge.r-project.org#panel.ablineq) to get the concrete functions (slope, intercept)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The general answer will be to use `HH::ancovaplot()` directly (rather than implicitly via `HH::ancova()`) along with **latticeExtra**'s handy `layer()` function and overloaded `+` operator. I'll leave it to you to work out the fiddly details required to make it look exactly how you want it to.

```
ancovaplot(Sodium ~ Calories * Type, data=hotdog) +
layer(panel.ablineq(lm(y ~ x), rot = TRUE, at = 0.5, pos = 3))
```

[image]